# Prevent file deletion

Tags: objective-c, macos, filesystems

I'm looking for a simple way of preventing a file from being deleted in MacOSX. I know there is always a way of deleting it, like loading the HD with another operating system, but I'm looking for some easy method to make it a bit difficult for someone without technical knowledge.

I tried changing the privileges of the containing folder to read only, and changing the owner to "nobody", but the user can easily delete it using finder with the admin password.

I've also tried opening the file with fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath, I thought it won't be possible to delete a file in use, but finder just deletes it without problem.

Is there a way to prevent a file from being deleted in MacOSX?

Comment: If you want to prevent file deletion even for people with admin password, then no way! Because admin privileges are intended exactly for this kind of things. Don't give admin privileges so easily...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Sure, but one of the functionalities of the app is to avoid deleting some specific files accidentally. The OS X default user has admin privileges with his password, so it isn't something I can or want to change. The thing is, why finder can delete a file that is in use?

Comment: Be aware that deleting a file in use doesn't mean that the application using it is unable to manipulate the file. A file is really deleted if: there is no more link (name if you prefer) onto it and no more process (application if you prefer) is using it (opened and not actually closed).

Comment: Also It would be better if an admin couldn't delete a file owned by some other admin. Forcing to change the ownership first.

Comment: different levels of admin ? Too complex to manage. Don't create admin account, and admin account should be aware about dangerous things, if not...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Ok, I understand!. About the file in use I was thinking in some kind of "exclusive file open" like in windows or some other file locking method. There isn't anything similar in OS X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to lock files, so that even root can't delete them.

Using the chflags command, various options are available:

```
arch    "archived flag"
opaque  "opaque flag"
nodump  "nodump flag"
sappnd  "system append-only flag"
schg    "system immutable flag"
uappnd  "user append-only flag"
uchg    "user immutable flag"
```

Assuming we have a file called `testFile`, do the following

```
chflags schg testfile
```

Attempting to delete the file, even as root, will be denied. Now, the only method to remove the file is to boot into Single User mode.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, you are a life saver, thank you!! For future readers, to unset the flag, in single user mode, it would be: chflags noschg testfile

Comment: For more details https://ss64.com/osx/chflags.html

Comment: As of MacOS 12.5 “Monterey” (if not earlier), single user mode seems no longer necessary to achieve `chflags noschg` — a simple `sudo` in the same environment will suffice.